# How to create Java classes for two array Json

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

I'm trying to create Java Pojo classes for following Json

https://www.reddit.com/r/MurderedByWords/comments/ervfco/trying_to_relate_to_their_viewers/.json

I just wanted to extract the comments, author, created_utc from the JSON. I couldn't figure it out as it has two arrays.

Can anyone help me to create it?

Edit:

```
public class Codebeautify {
 0 0O bject;
 1 1 Object;


 // Getter Methods 

 public 0 get0() {
  return 0O bject;
 }

 public 1 get1() {
  return 1 Object;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void set0(0 0O bject) {
  this .0 Object = 0O bject;
 }

 public void set1(1 1 Object) {
  this .1 Object = 1 Object;
 }
}
public class 1 {
 private String kind;
 Data DataObject;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String getKind() {
  return kind;
 }

 public Data getData() {
  return DataObject;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setKind(String kind) {
  this.kind = kind;
 }

 public void setData(Data dataObject) {
  this.DataObject = dataObject;
 }
}
public class Data {
 private String modhash;
 private String dist = null;
 ArrayList < Object > children = new ArrayList < Object > ();
 private String after = null;
 private String before = null;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String getModhash() {
  return modhash;
 }

 public String getDist() {
  return dist;
 }

 public String getAfter() {
  return after;
 }

 public String getBefore() {
  return before;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setModhash(String modhash) {
  this.modhash = modhash;
 }

 public void setDist(String dist) {
  this.dist = dist;
 }

 public void setAfter(String after) {
  this.after = after;
 }

 public void setBefore(String before) {
  this.before = before;
 }
}
public class 0 {
 private String kind;
 Data DataObject;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String getKind() {
  return kind;
 }

 public Data getData() {
  return DataObject;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setKind(String kind) {
  this.kind = kind;
 }

 public void setData(Data dataObject) {
  this.DataObject = dataObject;
 }
}
public class Data {
 private String modhash;
 private float dist;
 ArrayList < Object > children = new ArrayList < Object > ();
 private String after = null;
 private String before = null;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String getModhash() {
  return modhash;
 }

 public float getDist() {
  return dist;
 }

 public String getAfter() {
  return after;
 }

 public String getBefore() {
  return before;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setModhash(String modhash) {
  this.modhash = modhash;
 }

 public void setDist(float dist) {
  this.dist = dist;
 }

 public void setAfter(String after) {
  this.after = after;
 }

 public void setBefore(String before) {
  this.before = before;
 }
}
```

Comment: Two arrays wouldn't be valid JSON. If It was only one array, then it would be a List of objects (or POJOs),

Comment: It is a valid json as it is array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON returned by the URL in your question is an array having 2 objects.

You can use online tools like [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate the POJO classes (select source type as JSON).

Then you can use any popular json libary like Jackson or GSON to convert the json to POJO.

Root POJOs would be something like

```java
public class Root{
    private List<Item> items;
}
```

```java
public class Item {
    private Data data;

    private String kind;
}
```

JSON structure:
[image]

EDIT:
There is a restriction of 51200 characters at [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). For larger JSON, use [sodhanalibrary](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/)

Comment: I tried https://codebeautify.org/json-to-java-converter. it returns 0, 1 as objects. is it valid? how could I rename it? See edit.

Comment: @GK007 copy the json in raw format and if you then beautify it  you will see proper array of objects and then try json to java pojo conveter.

Comment: @GK007 Updated my question to reflect root classes. you can generate rest of the classes at http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/